# Is there a way to insert 2D slice into sqlite database?

Tags: go

I have requirement where the request json can be parsed using 2d slice and I can get each field of the 2d slices by iterating over them. But how can I push that slice to sqlite database and get it back as a 2d slice.
Here is my sample JSON:

```
{
    "emailList": [
        [
            "akki@gmail.com",
            "bakki@gmail.com"
        ],
        [
            "lakki@gmail.com",
            "jakki@gmail.com"
        ]
    ]
}
```

and here is my sample struct:

```
type User struct {
    EmailList [][]string `json:"emailList"`
}
```

Now I have write a go code which reads the sample json parses it using the given struct and insert it into sqlite db. Also read the record from DB and construct the JSON from the record.

Comment: You can always save the JSON to a text column in the database.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian I don't want to save the whole json but only the values corresponding to key in json. So here the value is a 2d slice.

Comment: @Ash Are you asking about what db schema architecture would it be ideal to use or are you asking for Go code for a particular schema. Could you give a little more context as per what these emails are to be stored against?

Comment: @KarthikNayak I basically have a column called `EmailList` as varchar in the table and I want to save my 2D slice shown in the question into that field using go code. And also want to be able to parse this field back into 2dslice.

Comment: How would the exact value look like after you inserted it?

Comment: @zerkms it will look like this: 
`[
        [
            "akki@gmail.com",
            "bakki@gmail.com"
        ],
        [
            "lakki@gmail.com",
            "jakki@gmail.com"
        ]
    ]`

Comment: So serialise `user.EmailList` then?

Comment: @Ash Wouldn't it make more sense to instead have another table which is Emails, where you'd have a Foreign key which would point to this table. This way each of the emails in your list is an entry in the Emails table pointing to this table via Foreign Key.